# NSManagedObjectMOdel fails to initialize on iOS 5 and above

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, core-data

I have a project which works fine when I build it for iOS 4.x, however it fails when I build it for iOS 5.x with a crash.  To clarify, the 4.x build will run fine on iOS 5.1, however when I build against 5.0 or 5.1, I get the crash described below.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel == nil)
    {
        __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];  //crash  
    }

    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

I checked the docs, and supposedly supplying `nil` as  for the parameter is supposed to default to the main bundle.  Anyone know if anything that changed with CoreData that would cause this to happen?

For what it's worth, I've run the "Analyze" tool and no memory leaks or anything unusual is being reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to come up with a work around.  I created a new single-view project and then copied the generated code to initialize the managed object model into my new project.  My hunch is that that `[[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]` works differently in the iOS 5.1 SDK and perhaps it wasn't able to find my data model as it wasn't stored in the project root but a separate "Data" folder.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PreferencesModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

Comment: but not able to work in ios 4.3 with above code.work fine in above ios 5

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually describe the crash or provide any error messages but the following StackOverflow question has a solution to a crash that may help:

[Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7966149/558933)

Comment: I thought we were on to something here, but no such luck.  I've managed to solve the problem though.