# UIManagedDocument initWithURL blows with NSArray error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am completely flummoxed. This code:

```
 NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *documentURL=[fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
    documentURL = [documentURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"TrackerDB"];
    self.document = [UIManagedDocument alloc];
    self.document = [self.document initWithFileURL:documentURL];
```

produces this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

(I separated the alloc and init into two lines so I could see where it's blowing. It's the initWithFileURL that bombs, as soon as I hit "step into.")

self.document, by the way, is a `@property (strong,nonatomic) UIManagedDocument *` and the URL is:

**@"file://localhost/Users/rick/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/3FEA801E-9279-45A7-9606-853124A111C4/Documents/TrackerDB"**

which is exactly as expected. So, as I said, I'm baffled. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Just clean the build and rerun again BTW put some breakpoints to check your code where it is creating problem

Answer (score 0):

As the error you are getting relates to passing a nil pointer to a NSMutableArray method and you aren't working with arrays here, I would say the issue is most likely not with your code. I also read through it and couldn't find a problem. The issue is most likely with your simulator, which can have problems from time to time. It is a good idea to reset the settings and create a new build. The issue is handled well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966149/core-data-crash-nsarraym-insertobjectatindex-object-cannot-be-nil), and directly relates to this same issue when working with Core Data.

Comment: Alas, no luck. Deleted all that stuff, performed a Clean, same error. It appears there's something corrupted in the project; I copied the offending code into an empty project and it runs. Fortunately I wasn't too far along in this project, so I can just start over; if I figure anything out, I'll post a final follow-up comment here for future reference. Thanks, @jdkahn90, for letting me know it wasn't my code!